# HOWTO use the parser many times?

Tags: c++, antlr4

**SQLParser.h:**

```
class SQLParser{
/*____Variables____*/
private:
    std::string _vendor;
    antlr4::CommonTokenStream* _tokenStream;
    antlr4::Parser* _parser;
    antlr4::Lexer* _lexer;

/*____Functions____*/
public:
    SQLParser(const std::string& Vendor);
    ~SQLParser();
    antlr4::CommonTokenStream* get_tokens(const std::string& text);
    std::vector<std::string> get_lexems(const std::string& text);
    antlr4::ParserRuleContext* parse(const std::string& text);
    bool check_syntax(const std::string& text);
    void print_string_tree(const std::string& text);    // parse and print in LISP format
};
```

**SQLParser.cpp:**

```
...
CommonTokenStream* SQLParser::get_tokens(const std::string& text){
    (dynamic_cast<ANTLRInputStream*>(_lexer->getInputStream()))->load(text);
    _tokenStream->reset();
    _tokenStream->fill();
    return _tokenStream;
}

std::vector<std::string> SQLParser::get_lexems(const std::string& text){
    get_tokens(text);

    std::vector<std::string> lexems;
    for(auto token : _tokenStream->getTokens()) {
        lexems.push_back(token->getText());
    }
    return lexems;
}

ParserRuleContext* SQLParser::parse(const std::string& text){
    get_tokens(text);

    _parser->setInputStream(_tokenStream);
    ParserRuleContext* tree;
    try{
        if(_vendor == "tsql"){
            tree = (dynamic_cast<tsqlParser*>(_parser))->root();
        }
        if(_vendor == "mysql"){
            tree = (dynamic_cast<mysqlParser*>(_parser))->root();
        }
    }
    catch(std::_Nested_exception<ParseCancellationException>& e){
        return nullptr;
    }
    return tree;
}
```

An object *SQLParser* is created for each concrete *vendor*.
**I want to use this object to parse several input texts**. But I have problems with TokenStream's size. I expected that its size will changing dynamically. 
For example, *main* like this:
**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <antlr4-runtime.h>
#include "SQLParser.h"

using namespace antlr4;

int main(){
    SQLParser parser("tsql");
    std::cout << "'select 1;': ";
    parser.print_string_tree("select 1;");
    std::cout << "\n\n'select 1,2,3;': ";
    parser.print_string_tree("select 1,2;");
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

is giving output like this:

```
'select 1;': (root (sql_clauses (sql_clause (dml_clause (select_statement (query_expression (query_specification select (select_list (select_list_elem (expression (constant 1)))))) ;)))) <EOF>)

'select 1,2,3;': (root (sql_clauses (sql_clause (dml_clause (select_statement (query_expression (query_specification select (select_list (select_list_elem (expression (constant 1)))))) ,)))) )
```

How should I use TokenStream to avoid this error?

Comment: *"I want to use this object to parse several input texts"* => if the C++ API is like the C# one, you're not supposed to do that - you create another stream/lexer/parser instead. By default, the lexer caches the tokens. *Why* would you want to do it in a different way? [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271659)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup like you. Context class keeps lexer + parser + listeners etc. together which act as a whole. To restart parsing with new input you have to make your token stream reload all tokens again. In my context class I do it so:

```
struct MySQLParserContextImpl : public MySQLParserContext {
  ANTLRInputStream input;
  MySQLLexer lexer;
  CommonTokenStream tokens;
  MySQLParser parser;
  ContextErrorListener errorListener;

  bool caseSensitive;
  std::vector<ParserErrorInfo> errors;

  ...

  ParseTree *parse(const std::string &text, MySQLParseUnit unit) {
    input.load(text);
    return startParsing(false, unit);
  }

  bool errorCheck(const std::string &text, MySQLParseUnit unit) {
    parser.removeParseListeners();
    input.load(text);
    startParsing(true, unit);
    return errors.empty();
  }

private:
  ParseTree *parseUnit(MySQLParseUnit unit) {
    switch (unit) {
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateSchema:
        return parser.createDatabase();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateTable:
        return parser.createTable();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateTrigger:
        return parser.createTrigger();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateView:
        return parser.createView();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateFunction:
        return parser.createFunction();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateProcedure:
        return parser.createProcedure();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateUdf:
        return parser.createUdf();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateRoutine:
        return parser.createRoutine();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateEvent:
        return parser.createEvent();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateIndex:
        return parser.createIndex();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuGrant:
        return parser.grant();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuDataType:
        return parser.dataTypeDefinition();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateLogfileGroup:
        return parser.createLogfileGroup();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateServer:
        return parser.createServer();
      case MySQLParseUnit::PuCreateTablespace:
        return parser.createTablespace();
      default:
        return parser.query();
    }
  }

  ParseTree *startParsing(bool fast, MySQLParseUnit unit) {
    errors.clear();
    lexer.reset();
    lexer.setInputStream(&input); // Not just reset(), which only rewinds the current position.
    tokens.setTokenSource(&lexer);

    parser.reset();
    parser.setBuildParseTree(!fast);

    // First parse with the bail error strategy to get quick feedback for correct queries.
    parser.setErrorHandler(std::make_shared<BailErrorStrategy>());
    parser.getInterpreter<ParserATNSimulator>()->setPredictionMode(PredictionMode::SLL);

    ParseTree *tree;
    try {
      tree = parseUnit(unit);
    } catch (ParseCancellationException &) {
      if (fast)
        tree = nullptr;
      else {
        // If parsing was cancelled we either really have a syntax error or we need to do a second step,
        // now with the default strategy and LL parsing.
        tokens.reset();
        parser.reset();
        parser.setErrorHandler(std::make_shared<DefaultErrorStrategy>());
        parser.getInterpreter<ParserATNSimulator>()->setPredictionMode(PredictionMode::LL);
        tree = parseUnit(unit);
      }
    }

    if (errors.empty() && !lexer.hitEOF) {
      // There is more input than needed for the given parse unit. Make this a fail as we don't allow
      // extra input after the specific rule.
      // This part is only needed if the grammar has no explicit EOF token at the end of the parsed rule.
      Token *token = tokens.LT(1);
      ParserErrorInfo info = {"extraneous input found, expecting end of input",
                              token->getType(),
                              token->getStartIndex(),
                              token->getLine(),
                              token->getCharPositionInLine(),
                              token->getStopIndex() - token->getStartIndex() + 1};
      errors.push_back(info);
    }
    return tree;
  }
  ...
```